# windows phone 8 issues with trusting SSL certificates

Tags: ssl, windows-phone-8, webclient

I want to retrieve JSON files from a secure server using WebClient but my Windows Phone 8 doesn't let me as WebCLient throws an exception if it doesn't trust the SSL certificate.

The problem is that it doesn't trust most of them; Internet Explorer shows me a warning, which I can ignore by adding the certificate, but WebClient doesn't let me do that, it just blocks most of SSL sites - for example:

https://google.com

https://www.digicert.com

With HTTP everything works fine; My iPhone and Android apps are working perfectly with the service.

Is there any way to fix this or bypass SSL checking altogether?

Comment: Go for HttpClient and check it again.

Comment: HttpClient doesn't check sertificates?

Comment: Hi, have you solved your problem ?

Comment: yes. I had wrong date on my device! when I changed it to the right one all certificates became valid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your phone's time.  If the system time/date is way off SSL will break.  This is common on all platforms.

It is not possible to bypass SSL checking.

Comment: hmmm, time is really way off! I never set it up properly!